# Positive-definiteness of matrix with $|a_{ij}| \leq \frac{1}{ij}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

Let $A$ be a $N\times N$-matrix with elements 
$$
a_{ii}=1 \quad\text{and}\quad
a_{ij} = \frac{1}{ij}  \quad\text{for}~ i\neq j.
$$
Then $A$ is positive-definite, as can be easily seen from
$$
x^T A x = \sum_i x_i^2 + \sum_{i \neq j} \frac{x_i x_j}{ij} 
\geq
\sum_i \frac{x_i^2}{i^2} + \sum_{i \neq j} \frac{x_i x_j}{ij} 
=
\left(\sum_i \frac{x_i}{i}\right)^2 \geq 0.
$$

Assume now that $A$ is a real symmetric $N\times N$-matrix with elements 
$$
\tag{1}
a_{ii}=1 \quad\text{and}\quad
|a_{ij}| \leq \frac{1}{ij}  \quad\text{for}~ i\neq j.
$$

> Is it possible to show that $A$ is also positive-definite (or positive-semidefinite)?

---

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3564214/positive-definiteness-of-matrix-with-0-leq-a-ij-leq-frac1ij) I posted a refinement of this question by assuming $0 \leq a_{ij} \leq \frac{1}{ij}$ for $i \neq j$ in $(1)$.

Comment: it may be better to think of this in terms of congruence transforms -- with diagonal $D := \text{diag}(1,2,...,n)$ then your original $A$ is congruent to $DAD = D^2 - I +\mathbf {11}^T$  and for $\big \Vert \mathbf x \big \Vert_2 = 1$ we have $\mathbf x^T DAD \mathbf x  = \mathbf x^T \big(D^2 - I +\mathbf {11}^T\big)\mathbf x \geq \mathbf x^T\big(D^2 - I\big)\mathbf x \geq 0$  where the second lower bound is met with equality *iff* $\mathbf x \propto \mathbf e_1$, in which case the first bound is strict... this shows positive definiteness.

Comment: Could you say something about the origin of this question ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Positive-definiteness of such matrix appears as a sufficient condition for the completeness in $L^2(0,1)$ of a certain perturbation of the system of square wave functions, and follows from the Paley-Wiener stability theorem (see, e.g., Theorem 9.2 in Singer's "Bases in Banach Spaces I"). The values $\frac{1}{ij}$ are scalar products of corresponding square waves. Basically, if certain perturbations of the system of square waves are sufficiently small, then the elements $a_{ij}$ have to be close to $\frac{1}{ij}$, and, presumably, the completeness property should be kept.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I posted some years ago a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1885456) about structured matrices having a certain similarity with yours but with complex eigenvalues. I have never had satisfactory answers. If, by chance, you have an idea...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's false.

Choose $N=20$ and, for every $i\not= j$, $A_{i,j}=\dfrac{-1}{ij}$. $A$ admits a negative eigenvalue $\approx -0.04$.

It suffices to consider your first matrix $A$ -denoted by $A0$ (with $A0_{i,j}=1/(ij)$)-.

After, increase $N$ until $\rho(A0)> 2$.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed, you are right. But I've just realized that in the actual matrix which I work with (it comes from approximation theory) all elements are *positive*. Could you advice me, please, should I post a new question about it, or there is also a simple counterexample or a way to get a result?

Comment: If the $(a_{i,j})$ are $> 0$, then I think it's right, but I haven't really thought about this new situation. It's better that you post a new question.

Comment: 1) I realize that simulations don't give always good hints. 2) In fact, one can start from $N=13$ where the smallest eigenvalue is $-0.004$.

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes, the simulations work poorly when counterexamples are in "corners".

Comment: An odd fact : on an experimental, basis, vector $V$ with coordinates $V_k=k/(1+k^2)$ is a very good approximation of the eigenvector associated to the first (negative) eigenvalue.

Answer (score 4):

**Precise computations dealing with the solution by loup blanc**:

Let 
$$A_N=\begin{pmatrix}
1&-1/2&-1/3&\cdots&-1/N\\
-1/2&1&-1/6&\cdots&-1/(2N)\\
-1/3&-1/6&1&\cdots&-1/(3N)\\
\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots\\
-1/N&-1/(2N)&-1/(3N)&\cdots&1\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

(diagonal elements equal to $1$, off-diagonal elements $(A_N)_{ij}=-\dfrac{1}{ij}$.)

We are going to obtain a formula for $\det(A_N)$ (formula (2)) showing a certain value $N_0$ exists such that

$$\text{for all} \ N \geq N_0, \ \ \det(A_{N})<0$$

Let us use the following formula for the determinant of an invertible matrix $M$ and (column) vectors $U,V \in \mathbb{R^n}$

$$\det(M+UV^T)=\det(M)(1+V^TM^{-1}U)\tag{1}$$

([matrix-determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma))

If we take :

$$\begin{cases}M&=&diag(1+1/1^2,1+1/2^2,1+1/3^2, \cdots 1+1/N^2)\\
U&=&(1,1/2,1/3,\cdots 1/N)^T\\
V&=&-U\end{cases},$$

we have :

$$A_N=M+UV^T.$$

Therefore, using (1) :

$$\det(A_N)=\prod_{k=1}^N \left(1+\dfrac{1}{k^2}\right) \times \left(1-\sum_{k=1}^N \dfrac{1}{k} \times \dfrac{1}{1+\tfrac{1}{k^2}} \times \dfrac{1}{k}\right)$$

$$\det(A_N)=\prod_{k=1}^N \left(1+\dfrac{1}{k^2}\right) \times \left(1-\sum_{k=1}^N \dfrac{1}{k^2+1}\right)\tag{2}$$

But the following series is convergent with sum :

$$\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \dfrac{1}{k^2+1}=\dfrac12\left(\pi \coth \pi -1 \right)\approx 1.07667...> 1$$

(see [a proof here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1070413) or [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1226926)).

Therefore, the content of the second parenthesis in (2) becomes negative beyond a certain $N_0$ as expected ; thus $\det(A_N)<0 $ for $N \geq N_0$ : $A_N$ cannot be semi-definite positive for  $N \geq N_0$.

This value $N_0$ happens to be $13$ as "forecasted" by numerical attempts.

**Remarks :**

1) The first part of the determinant above tends, when $N \to \infty$ to the following convergent infinite product (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2039426)) :

$$\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(1+\dfrac{1}{k^2}\right)=\dfrac{\text{sinh} \ \pi}{\pi}\approx 3.676078.$$

As a consequence, for very large values of $N$,

$$\det(A_N) \approx \dfrac{1}{2}\left(\dfrac{1}{\pi}(3 \sinh \pi)- \cosh \pi\right) = -0.28186..$$

2) It is instructive to plot the eigenvalues of $A_N$ (which are all real because $A_N$ is symmetrical). See figure (horizontal axis : values of $N$ from $N=1$ to $N=200$). Different aspects can be underlined, in particular the fact that there is a unique negative eigenvalue ($\approx -0.10720$  for $N$ sufficiently large), a huge cluster just above $1$, and separate values at $\approx 1.0858226$, $\approx 1.176735$, and $\approx 1.593347$.

These curves are either increasing or decreasing as a consequence of [Cauchy interlacing theorem for symmetric matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem).

[image]

A possible connection :(https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S002437951200198X).

Comment: @loup blanc I have given some precisions in this answer about the minimal size $A$ must have in order to have $\det(A)<0$ : I find back in this way $N_0=13$...

Comment: Very elegant approach!