# Are there any "visual proofs" that have no formal written proof?

Tags: visualization, formal-proofs

As the title says, are there any problems that have been "solved" using a visual proof but which have not been solved via a written proof?

Comment: Here is a very recent one in my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3561500) : the figure shows that matrix $A_N$ has 4 special eigenvalues, but I am unable to explain why...

Comment: I don't think so. A "visual proof" is really just a picture which intuitively suggests a logical argument that proves the given proposition; if a picture doesn't suggest such an argument, then it isn't really a visual proof so much as it is interesting diagram.

Comment: If there is no way to make the "visial proof" a "written proof" then it does not deserve the lable "proof". Essential in mathematics is logics which is associated with "words".